# Sliding Week Comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, refactoring

I want to compare data from the current week (1 through 52) to the data from two weeks prior.  I need to make sure that when the new-year boundary is crossed, the comparison keeps working. I have a working predicate, like this:

```
WHERE ( DATEPART(ww,MA.DateOpen) + 1 ) % 52 = DATEPART(ww,@ImportDate) - 1
```

The above logic works, but it does not account for proximate years.  In other words, unwanted data from week 'X' of all prior years will be included in the comparison.  So the predicate must be expanded to account for years, which in turn requires handling the new year boundary: week 1 of 2012 should be compared against week 51 of 2011.

How can this be done without a verbose looking predicate?

**update:**
This question is complicated by the need for "week of year" to be treated as Tuesday through Tuesday.  My current "correct" attempt is embodied in the [VerboseCheck] case below.

```
SET DATEFIRST 2
DECLARE @ImportDate date = '2011-1-4'
DECLARE @DateOpen date = '2010-12-20'
select @ImportDate, 
YEAR(@DateOpen),
DATEPART(ww, @DateOpen),
YEAR(DATEADD(dd,-14,@ImportDate)), 
DATEPART(ww,DATEADD(dd,-14,@ImportDate)),
CASE WHEN 
  YEAR(@DateOpen) + DATEPART(ww, @DateOpen) = 
  YEAR(DATEADD(dd,-14,@ImportDate)) + DATEPART(ww,DATEADD(dd,-14,@ImportDate))
  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [VerboseCheck],
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF (ww, @DateOpen, @ImportDate) =2
  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [SimpleCheck]
```

The [SimpleCheck] would be perfect, but it gives a different answer than [VerboseCheck]. If I advance @DateOpen one more day, then the two give the same answer.  This suggests that both are not honoring the DATEFIRST evaluation in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like DateDiff would be best used here. However as you noted DATEFIRST [is indeed not respected](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/239958/datediff-function-and-the-first-day-of-the-week).

So we just add [Itzik Ben-Gan's solution](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/sql-server/datediff-with-the-week-part) and we get

```
 WHERE DATEDIFF (ww, 
    DATEADD( day, -@@DATEFIRST , @DateOpen),
    DATEADD( day, -@@DATEFIRST , @ImportDate)
    ) =2
```

Comment: I updated my question to include the DATEFIRST issue, which I think prevents DATEDIFF from working as proposed.

Comment: So tues-Mon is supposed to define a week rather than Sat-sun

Comment: Actually I checked and DateDiff respects it fine but with Tuesday as the start of the week, but there are 53 weeks in 2011 when `Datefirst = 2` are you sure this is supposed to be compared to the 51st week of 2011 or is it (Number of week in 2011 - 1)

Comment: I've updated my question again, with sample code, showing how the DATEDIFF gives a different answer.

Comment: Brent. Nice update. Sorry I was wrong. I was using bad inputs (reasoning about dates can be a pain). I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

why not just `DATEADD('dd', -14, DateOpen)`?

Comment: That's not quite right. Since a date in the 51st week of 2011 and the 1st week in 2012 may not be exactly 14 days apart

Answer (score 0):

Would something like the following work to compare the years?

```
WHERE ( DATEPART(ww,MA.DateOpen) + 1 ) % 52 = DATEPART(ww,@ImportDate) - 1
AND YEAR(MA.DateOpen)=YEAR(DATEADD(d, -14, @ImportDate))
```